# Подскажите, почему не работает скрипт, что бы виджет вылезал при заходе на сайт, через n число секунд?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

У меня он выдвигается только при наведении, а надо что бы еще и при заходе на сайт, через n время тоже показался.

```js
    function makeSlideoutVisible(){
        document.getElementById("slideout").style.visibility = "visible";
        console.log("!");
    }
    var n = 1; //секунды
    setTimeout(makeSlideoutVisible, n*1000);
```

```css
#slideout {
  position: fixed;
  bottom:220px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 90px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  z-index:3;
}
#slideout_inner {
  position: fixed;
  bottom:31px;
  background-color: #fff;
  right: -250px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
 width: 250px;
 color:#808080;
 height: 240px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  z-index:3;
}
#slideout_inner a {
 color: #7F613E;
}
#slideout_inner h3{
  padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
#slideout_inner p{
 padding-left: 10px;
}
.nyaregok{
background: url("../img/navigation-right-frame.png") no-repeat;
 height: 48px;
    width: 48px;
  cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 14px;
}
.nyaok .leftinput{
 width: 129px;
}
.innyaok{
width: 185px;
  float: left;
}
.okimput{
    float: left;
    height: 41px;
    width: 49px;
}
#slideout:hover {
  right: 250px;
}
#slideout:hover #slideout_inner {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
      <div class="container">
      <div id="slideout">
  <div><img style="float: right; background-color: #fff; border: 5px solid #7F613E; border-radius: 30px; padding: 4px; color: #7F613E;" src="img/withis.png" alt="Привет! "></div>
  <div id="slideout_inner">
  <div class="nyamessage"> 
    <h3>ФОКУСЫ НАЧАЛИСЬ</h3>
    <br>
    <p>Давайте вместе веселиться ! .</p>
    <p>Ведь это так здорово!</p><br>
    <a class="clickMe" href="#">Поиграть с клоунами</a>
  </div>
            </div>
  </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте на событие onload страницы добавить таймер, в котором найдете нужный элемент и проставите нужный класс , отвечающий за выплывание.

Comment: https://codepen.io/blodark/pen/qjxqKR

Comment: используйте метод addEventListener() у объекта window, для подписки на событие onload, для того чтобы таймер запустился после загрузки страницы полностью.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Непонятно, почему Вы решили, что `visibility = "visible"` сделает то, что Вам надо, тогда как в стилях прописаны совершенно другие вещи.

```
function showSlideout(){
  document.getElementById("slideout").style.right = "250px";
  document.getElementById("slideout_inner").style.right = "0px";
  console.log("!");
}
function hideSlideout(){
  document.getElementById("slideout").style.right = "";
  document.getElementById("slideout_inner").style.right = "";
  console.log("-");
}
var n = 1, m = 3; //секунды
setTimeout(showSlideout, n*1000);
setTimeout(hideSlideout, m*1000);
```

или

```
function toggleSlideout(show){
  document.getElementById("slideout").style.right = show? "250px" : "";
  document.getElementById("slideout_inner").style.right = show? "0px" : "";
  console.log(show? "!" : "-");
}
var n = 1, m = 3; //секунды
setTimeout(toggleSlideout, n*1000, true);
setTimeout(toggleSlideout, m*1000, false);
```

Да, еще. Вы на сайте уже больше месяца, можно сказать - опытный участник. Часто получаете по несколько ответов на Ваши вопросы. Здесь принято отмечать принятый ответ щелкнув на галочку слева от него. Этим Вы даете понять людям, которые Вам отвечают, что их ответы Вам небезразличны.

Comment: Спасибо Игорь, если я не ошибаюсь, то только над 1 из 4 записей не поставил  отметку. А так, всегда ставлю, и вам тоже.

Comment: Игорь, смотрите, он у нас откроется и в таком положении и останется, а той же командой, можно его назад отправить ?

Comment: @ErikSpichak Понимаю, что Вы, вероятно, голосуете за ответы на Ваши вопросы, - это Вы делаете правильно, спора нет. Однако, автор вопроса кроме голосования может еще принять ответ, как "правильный" или "наиболее полезный", щелкнув на значок "галочка" слева от ответа - ниже стрелок "вверх/вниз". Сейчас допишу.

Comment: Да, увидел, прошу прощения, не видел галочку....

Comment: Спасибо большое !